# Likelihood function of an increment process driven by fractional Brownian motion

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, stochastic-processes

I'm studying the following equation in the context of population dynamics
$$\tag1
    dX_t = \mu X_t dt + \sigma X_t dB^H_t
$$
where $B^H$ is the fractional Brownian motion (fBm) of Hurst parameter $H\in(0,1)$, that is a continuous Gaussian process starting at zero, with $B^H_t \sim \mathcal N(0,t^{2H})$ and with covariance $\mathbb E[B^H_t B^H_s] = \frac12(|t|^{2H}+|s|^{2H}-|t-s|^{2H})$.

According to the value of $H$

- if $H = 1/2$ then $B^H$ is the classical Brownian motion
- if $H < 1/2$ then increments of $B^H$ are negatively correlated
- if $H > 1/2$ then increments of $B^H$ are positively correlated

Moreover, the increment process $B^H_{t+1}-B^H_{t}$ is called fractional Gaussian noise (fGn) and has covariance $\gamma(k) = \frac12(|k-1|^{2H}-2|k|^{2H}+|k+1|^{2H})$.

---

To run numerical simulations, we first have to find estimators for the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

In this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4581546) the researches derive the maximum likelihood function in this way.

Let $f,g$ be two functions of $X_t$ and of $\theta$, vector of unknown parameters. Consider
$$\tag2
    dX_t = f(X_t,\theta) dt + g(X_t,\theta) dB^H_t
$$
the first and second moments of the increments of $X$ are given by
$$
   \mathbb E[dX|X,t] = f(X_t,\theta) dt
$$
$$
   \mathbb E[(dX)^2|X,t] = g^2(X_t,\theta) (dt)^{2H}.
$$

Partitioning $[0,T]$ as $0 = t_0 < t_1 < ... < t_N = T$ s.t. $\Delta t = t_{i+1}-t_i = T/N$, the SDE $(2)$ can be approximated by Euler-Maruyama method as
$$\tag3
    X_0 = x_0,\quad X_{n+1} = X_n + f(X_n,\theta)\Delta t + g(X_n,\theta)\Delta B^H_n 
$$
where $\Delta B^H_n = B^H_{t_{n+1}}-B^H_{t_n}$ (in the mentioned paper, $\Delta B^H_n$ is not explicitly defined, but I guess that the definition is the one that I wrote here) is the fGn and $0 \le n \le N-1$.

The probability density function of $(X_{n+1}, t_{n+1})$ starting at $(X_n,t_n)$ is then
$$\tag4
    \color{red}{p_X} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi g^2(X_n,\theta)(\Delta t)^{2H}}} \exp\Bigg(-\frac{(X_{n+1}-X_n-f(X_n,\theta)\Delta t)^2}{2g^2(X_n,\theta)(\Delta t)^{2H}}\Bigg)
$$
and the joint density gives the likelihood function $\mathcal L$, whose maximizers are the estimates of the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

For the initial sde $(1)$ we have $f(X_t,\theta) = \mu X_t$ and $g(X_t,\theta) = \sigma X_t$, hence
$$\tag5
    \color{red}{\mathcal L(\mu,\sigma) = \prod_{n=0}^{N-1}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2X^2_n(\Delta t)^{2H}}} \exp\Bigg(-\frac{(X_{n+1}-X_n-\mu X_n\Delta t)^2}{2\sigma^2X^2_n(\Delta t)^{2H}}\Bigg)
$$
$\log$ is strictly increasing, so by considering the log-likelihood $\ell = \log\mathcal L$
$$
    \ell(\mu,\sigma) = -\frac12 \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \log(2\pi\sigma^2X^2_n(\Delta t)^{2H}) - \frac12 \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{(X_{n+1}-X_n-\mu X_n\Delta t)^2}{\sigma^2X^2_n(\Delta t)^{2H}}
$$
we can simplify the computations, and the maximizers of $\ell$ maximize $\mathcal L$ too.

By imposing $\dfrac{\partial\ell}{\partial\mu} = 0$ and $\dfrac{\partial\ell}{\partial\sigma} = 0$, we find the estimators
$$
\hat\mu = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{X_{n+1}-X_n}{N\Delta t X_n} \quad \text{and} \quad \hat\sigma^2 = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{(X_{n+1}-X_n-\mu X_n\Delta t)^2}{N(\Delta t)^{2H}X^2_n}
$$

---

The first question is related to the first $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ term: is the formula $(4)$ for the pdf of the increments of the process $X$, defined by $(3)$, correct?

The second question is related to the second $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ term: is the formula $(5)$ for the joint density (likelihood function) of the increments of the process $X$, defined by $(3)$, correct?

About the second question, my doubt is that since the increments of the fBm are not independent, maybe also the increments of the process $X$, defined by $(3)$, driven by the fBm are not independent. If this was the case, then we could not write the joint density of the increments of $X$ as the product of the individual densities. How to prove if the increments of $X$ are independent or not?

Comment: Hi: If the increments, $X_{n+1} - X_{n}$ are normal and independent with that mean and variance ( i.e $E(dX| X,t)$ and $E(dx^2| X,t)$ ) then 4) looks correct to me.  But I'm not familiar with the Euler-Maryama method so that's all I can say.

Comment: Note that 3) makes it seems that $X_{n+1}$ is only dependent on $X_{n}$ which would make the increment, $X_{n+1} - X_{n}$ independent but I'm not totally sure if 3) implies that because of those other terms ?

Comment: @mlofton The increments $X_{n+1} - X_{n}$ are normal but I don't know if they are independent. The problem is that the increments $B^H_{t_{n+1}}-B^H_{t_n}$ are not independent. Maybe you are right by saying that $X_{n+1}$ is only dependent on $X_n$ and so the increment is independent.

Comment: If the $B^{H}_{t_{n}}$ increments are not independent, then my guess is that the $X_{n}$ increments are not independent because then, according to 3), $X_{n+1} - X_{n}$ is dependent on the $\triangle B^{H}_{n}$ which is an increment.

Comment: Yes that's my guess too, I hope somebody could prove this fact

Comment: @sounwave: I realize that it may not be possible but, if the paper was publicly available, you might have more luck with someone ( not me. I'm not a math person) )  providing a proof.  Also, the paper at the link here looks pretty readable and possibly related to what you're trying to do. By the way, what is that you're are actually trying to do :). https://www.longdom.org/open-access/the-model-of-real-data-constructing-using-fractional-brownian-motion-2090-4908-1000149.pdf

Comment: if you don't get answers here, you may want to send (and I guess delete this one because cross posting is not appreciated ) to quant.stackexchange.com. This group has enormously talented people but there are people over at quant.stackexchange who are serious experts in  sde's which is really what this is about.